# Prove A function $f:\mathbb{R^{2}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^{2}}$ is continuous if the inverse image of every open set is open.

Tags: general-topology

I want to make sure **my proof is right**:

For an open set $F$, $f^{-1}[F]$ is open. Furthermore, $f\circ f^{-1}[F] \subset F$ because $f^{-1}[F] = \{x:f(x)\in F\}$. For every $p\in f^{-1}[F]$, there exists an open disk $D_{f(p)}\subset F$ containing $f(p)$ because $f(p)$ is an interior point of $F$. In conclusion, we can construct an open set $\bigcup_{p\in f^{-1}[F]}D_{f(p)}\subset F$, and $f$ is continuous.

The definition of *continuous* in this book is:

> A function $f:\mathbb{R^{2}}\rightarrow\mathbb{R^{2}}$ is *continuous* at a point $p\in \mathbb{R^{2}}$ iff for any open set $V_{f(p)}$ containing $f(p)$ there exists an open set $U_{p}$ containing $p$ such that $f[U_{p}]\subset V_{f(p)}$.

Comment: It's interesting to note that the definition of continuous function used in topology is that the inverse image of open sets are open. What you are tasked with doing here for $X=Y=\mathbb{R}^2$ is to prove that the definition in your book implies the topological definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a bit overcomplicated (with all the unions etc.). Just start with the definitions. $\mathbb{R}^2$ is irrelevant; in fact any topological space will do (we just need the notion of open sets).

Suppose $f$ has inverse images of open sets open.

Then show $f$ is continuous directly: Pick $p \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $V_{f(p)}$ be an open set that contains $f(p)$. Then $p \in f^{-1}[V_{f(p)}]$ and the latter set is open by assumption, so $p$ is interior in $f^{-1}[V_{f(p)}]$. So there is an open set $U_p$ containing $p$ such that $U_p \subseteq f^{-1}[V_{f(p)}]$, where the last inclusion is equivalent to $f[U_p] \subseteq V_{f(p)}$ as required. So $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Your proof is very simple, and I really appreciate it. Can I ask you if my proof is right, though it's a bit verbose?

Comment: @Il-seobBae I would not approve of it myself, as it lacks a clear structure. It just starts "at random" with the remark (in better notation) $f[f^{-1}[F]] \subseteq F$, while it's not even clear what $F$ is yet (arbitrary open?). It's much better to make clear what you are assuming at every stage. A good proof is like a story, with a clear beginning and ending.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll keep that in mind.